# Как с помощью .htaccess выдать 410 ошибку при некорректном URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, регулярные-выражения, mod_rewrite

**Добрый день!**

```
Предположим, если URL сайта имеет вид http://sayt.com/ , то открывается главная страница.

Если если URL сайта имеет вид http://sayt.com/index.php , то тоже открывается главная страница.

Как с помощью файла .htaccess выдать 410 ошибку, если:    
 или в запрашиваемом URL обнаружен знак & (амперсанда)    
 или в запрашиваемом URL вида index.php?page=qwerty заместо числового параметра страницы передаётся что-то иное.
```

У меня были следующие идеи по содержанию корневой файла .htaccess:  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteBase /  
    RewriteRule &|page=\D - [G]

```
При переходе по URL http://sayt.com/page=qwert успешно выдаёт 410, 
однако при необходимом виде URL вида http://sayt.com/index.php?page=f 410 не выдается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема ?

или что должно быть в файле .htaccess чтобы 410 выдавалась в обоих случаях ?

Заранее спасибо!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, вопрос решил следующим содержанием файла .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (&|page=\D)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [G]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема ?

В том, что для обработки query string нужно смотреть в сторону [RewriteCond по `%{QUERY_STRING}`](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString).